# abbyy cloud ocr SDK

Tags: ocr, abbyy

I am working on a project for school and I need an OCR, I downloaded the free trial from abbyy cloud ocr sdk but after reading all the documentation and API I still don't understand how to use the cloud service. Did anyone have an experience using that tool and can explain to me how it works or send me a demo code for how to use it?

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Actually, dragging and dropping files onto the GUI should work.

- Make sure that you have set the right recognition language. The default one is English.
- If some short text fragments are not recognized and you don’t need to save any pictures and tables, you can try to use the textExtraction profile. The request URL should be like http://cloud.ocrsdk.com/processImage?profile=textExtraction&exportFormat=pdfSearchable.
- If the document quality is poor, you can try to use field-level recognition (when text coordinates are specified directly). It could be tested using the same GUI sample (second tab).
- Note that the recommended resolution for font size 12-16pt is about 300 dpi ([more source image recommendations](http://ocrsdk.com/documentation/best-practices/image-recommendations/?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=comment&utm_campaign=smm)).

To get more detailed recommendations, you can send your images and Application ID to CloudOCRSDK@abbyy.com.